# Why does the "in" icon on my web page appear in the wrong place in IE8, but not firefox or chrome?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

On [my web page](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~mike/), I have a link to my LinkedIn profile in the Resume section that uses their icon.. Under Firefox and Chrome, it appears in the correct spot, between a pair of square brackets. However, under IE8 (I haven't tried IE7), the icon appears a couple lines below the brackets.

I validated against the w3.org [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.binghamton.edu%2F~mike&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en) and [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.binghamton.edu%2F~mike&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) validators, and it comes back clean from both.

What gives?

Comment: http://browsershots.org/ - for checking in various browsers (versions).

Comment: It seems that "in" only appears in the wrong spot in IE8 if you are viewing the page with compatibility mode turned on.

Comment: Thanks all! I took Priyank's hint and removed the padding for my list items, and the icon should appear in the right place now. Now I need to rework some of my CSS to get the rest of the page back into shape.

Comment: (I'm voting to close as it's no longer relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why IE is so weird to debug. Try with LI { padding: 0.0em }

Comment: Yes, I had some padding specified globally for LIs. I've removed it. I'll have to figure out another way to put space between my list items...